# Using the same files on different file systems

Tags: filesystems, portability

Suppose you have a C++ program that generates data to be saved on disk. You save it on your Windows Vista file system. Can you use it directly on another OS with a different file system (for example Mac OSX)?

Answer (score 0):

yes. if you can get it onto the other system, or have visibility from one to another.

The file system should not be changing file content.

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem that I think of is the different formats for end-of-line markers: \n under UNIX, \r\n under Windows. I am not sure what Mac OSX uses (as a Unix system it should use \n, but if I recall correctly, older Mac OSs used \r). Of course it is easy to write converters between the formats.

Answer (score 0):

That depends. Binary data will appear the same on all mainstream operating systems (where a byte is 8 bits; this is not necessarily true of embedded systems).

Files written in text mode may not "work" on all platforms out of the box, due to newline conventions (Windows uses `\r\n` for a newline, Unix-like systems `\n`) and character encoding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, given that your Operating System has the drivers to read both filesystems.

The `fopen` or equivalent calls are completely abstracted such that you don't have to worry about where it comes from. Data will be read the same way.